# Как зафиксировать иконку в Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-search-view

Мне необходимо отображать `SearchView` и кнопку добавления в `Toolbar` все хорошо, но когда раскрывается SearchView кнопка выталкивается до края экрана как показано ниже, как можно решить эту проблему? Есть ли способ зафиксировать иконку так чтобы она не смещалась?

[image]

Нашел подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976163/push-icons-away-when-expandig-searchview-in-android-toolbar), но это не сработало для меня

компоненты в файле `menu.xml`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_people"
    android:title="Редактирование"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_person"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

Comment: @DeKaNszn добавлено

Comment: @AmirShabanov попробуйте это searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);